# The most frequently occurring item in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a list in this table

```
public class Fruits
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to know what are the most frequent fruit in this table what is the code that appears to me this result
I am use

```
var max = db.Fruits.Max();
```

There is an error in that?

Comment: @DrewKennedy You should create an answer rather than a comment, because you have the right answer.

Comment: If there
apple
apple
apple
apple
apple
Orange
Orange
Lemon

I want to say something to me <apple>

Comment: @gretro My bad. Didn't think I'd have time for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public class Fruits
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name{ get; set; }
}


var Val = fruitList.GroupBy(x => x.ID,
                         (key, y) => y.MaxBy(x => x.ID).value)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Drew said in the comments, you want to GroupBy on the value that you care about (I did Name, since ID tends to be unique in most data structures) and then OrderByDescending based on the count.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var fruits = new List<Fruit> { new Fruit { ID = 1, Name = "Apple" }, new Fruit { ID = 2, Name = "Apple" }, new Fruit { ID = 3, Name = "Pear" } };   
        var most = fruits.GroupBy(f => f.Name).OrderByDescending(group => group.Count());
        Console.WriteLine(most.First().Key);
    }
}

public class Fruit
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In this case I knew what was in the table and if you do not know is it an apple or a banana I want to know what is the most frequent

Comment: @سلطاناليامي - Unsure of what you mean. This will be able to tell you what you are asking for without you knowing what it is. The only reason you can see it here is I needed to show test data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the name of the item that exists most in your list, first find the id that is most occurring:

```
var fruitAnon = fruits
        .GroupBy(item => item.ID)
        .Select(item => new {
            Key = item.Key,
            Count = item.Count()
        })
        .OrderByDescending(item => item.Count)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

This will return an anonymous object that will have the most frequent `id`, and the `count` represents the number of times it exists in the list. You can then find that object's name:

```
var fruit = fruits.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == fruitAnon.Key);
```

If you had a list like this:

```
List<Fruits> fruits = new List<Fruits>() {
    new Fruits { ID = 1, Name = "Apple" },
    new Fruits { ID = 1, Name = "Apple" },
    new Fruits { ID = 2, Name = "Orange" },
    new Fruits { ID = 2, Name = "Orange" },
    new Fruits { ID = 2, Name = "Orange" },
    new Fruits { ID = 2, Name = "Orange" }
};
```

Then:

```
Console.WriteLine(fruit.Name);
```

Would print `Orange`.